# NBAndroid issue build.xml:1: Premature end of file

Tags: java, android, xml, netbeans

I was using this https://borwell.com/2015/09/07/simple-android-app-in-netbeans/ to learn how to make my first android app and when i try to Clean, Build, Run or debug the error build.xml:1: Premature end of file. I when to my build file and it was empty. I was wounder if anyone has a solution for this?

EDIT:

It 24 hours ago when i was debugging and once i added more android versions it stopped working.